# Cannot load modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server

Tags: windows, apache, svn, module, webdav

Since `mod_dav_svn.so` and `mod_authz_svn.so` were not present in SVN (TortoiseSVN), I downloaded the files from https://github.com/nono303/win-svn/tree/master/vc15/x64 and moved them to `C:\Apache24\modules`.

I then added the following lines to the `httpd.conf` file in Apache24:

```
# Subversion Configuration
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

However, upon doing so, the service failed to start. Subsequently, the following error occurred:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 188 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: \x8ew\x92\xe8\x82\xb3\x82\xea\x82\xbd\x83\x82\x83W\x83\x85\x81[\x83\x8b\x82\xaa\x8c\xa9\x82\xc2\x82\xa9\x82\xe8\x82\xdc\x82\xb9\x82\xf1\x81
```

I am using Windows 11 with x64 architecture.

These comments are enabled:

```
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
```